# How to find an optimal match between two ordered categorical vectors?

Tags: r, categorical-data

Given two categorical vectors that are in an identical order, I wish to find the best/optimal match of categories. Categories would be lined up.

For example, I have two vectors

```
x=c("e","a","a","e","a");
y=c("2","1","2","2","1")
```

In this toy example, the best matches are "e" ~ "2" and "a" ~ "1", resulting in 1 mismatch. Otherwise, we would get many more mismatches. Further, I would transform `y` to follow category names of `x` as suggested by the best match:

```
y=c("e","a","e","e","a")
```

How can I carry this out with more categories and longer vectors?
Thank you!

Comment: How are you defining best here? is it simply the highest count of matching categories?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df<-data.frame(y=y, x=x, stringsAsFactors=F)
df

library(dplyr)
res<-df %>% group_by(x) %>% count(y) %>% top_n(1)
# or # df %>% group_by(x) %>% slice(which.max(table(y)) )

df$new<-new_y<-res$x[match(df$y,res$y)]
df
new_y
```